# Set a user's nickname in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So for my discord bot, i wanted to add a nick command. To do so i looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247353/node-change-user-nickname-with-discord-js) thread and adapted it for my code.

```
client.on("message", async message => {
    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command == "nick") {
        var userID = args[0].replace('<@', '').replace('>', '').replace('!', '');
        message.channel.send(userID);
        message.guild.members.get(args[0]).id.setNickname("test", "nick command executed");
        message.channel.send(`Successfully changed ${args[0]}'s nickname to "${message.channel.server.detailsOf(args[0]).nick}"`);
    }
});

client.login("token");
```

This, for some reason, outputs `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` to console, but successfully send `UserID` to the channel.

Why is that, and how can i "fix" it so it actually changes the users nickname?

Comment: Try: `console.log( message.guild.members.get(args[0]) )`

Comment: @JonasW.That, for some reason, outputs 0, even when i have 2 arguments: one mentioned user, and the new nickname.

Answer (score 3):

Whats happening in your code is that you're storing the changed version of `args[0]` in `userId`:

```js
var userID = args[0].replace('<@', '').replace('>', '').replace('!', '');
```

but then you're passing the unchanged `args[0]` into the `.get`:

```js
message.guild.members.get(args[0]).id.setNickname("test", "nick command executed");
```

So the code is running: `..get(<@...>)` which will return an error because that is not a valid id.

There are two things you should change:

1. Replace `args[0]` with `userId`
2. Remove `.id` from `message.guild.members.get(args[0]).id` because you will not be able to call setNickname afterwards.

Comment: I figured it out :P, this was a long time ago. Thanks anyway.