# Discord.js SetNickname Function Is Not Working

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a bot that gives a role and sets nickname of it's user.
My goal is if someone types " -verify SomeNickname " on the text channel the bot will set their nickname as SomeNickname and give them a certain role.

`mem.AddRole` is working without any errors  but `.setNickname` function is not working with anything.

The error is `TypeError: mem.setNickname is not a function`

This duplicate thread did not work for me: [Change user nickname with discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247353/change-user-nickname-with-discord-js)

I also tried:
 `message.member.setNickname` & `message.author.setNickname` &

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('-verify')) {
    message.author.setNickname({
      nick: message.content.replace('-verify ', '')
    });
  }
});
```

so far.

My code is:

```
module.exports = bot => bot.registerCommand('verify', (message, args)        => {  
  message.delete();
  var title = args.join(' ');
  var mem = message.member;
    mem.addRole('560564037583241227').catch(console.error);
    mem.setNickname(title);
}
```

The bot is giving the role without any problems but its not setting a nickname to the user. 
**Additional Info: Bot has every permission and im not trying to change server owner's nickname.**

The `message.member` object looks like this:

[image: object printout]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192867/discussion-on-question-by-orcuno-discord-js-setnickname-function-is-not-working).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As determined through the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192867/discussion-on-question-by-orcuno-discord-js-setnickname-function-is-not-working), your current code is using `discord.io`, not `discord.js`. These libraries are different, so that's the source of your various issues.

I'd recommend using `discord.js` from now on, but you may have to restructure your code a little bit. Documentation can be found [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) for future reference.

If you'd like to continue using `discord.io`, you can edit your question to be clearer, although from our conversation you don't intend to.