# Discord.js permission

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot using the discord.js module, and i'm planning to make these features:

1. Kicking (and blocking) users
2. Setting the user's nickname
3. Managing channels
4. Assigning & Creating Roles
5. Editing & Creating the channel

And I want to limit these (section 1, 2, 4) capabilities to a Server Moderator or Manager. What permissions bit flag should I use? Currently I am using `1475677686`.

### Here is my code

`Kick Command`:

```js
if(!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")){
  return message.reply("You don't have permission to do that.");
}

if(message.mentions.users.size === 0){
  return message.reply("Usage: `_kick [mention]`");
}

message.mentions.members.forEach((member) => {
  member.ban({
    reason: "Banned by admin",
    days: 7
  }).then((value) => {
    message.reply("Succeed to kick member");
  }).catch((error) => {
    message.reply("Internal bot error");
    console.error(error);
  });
});
```

`Nickname Command`:

```js
if(!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")){
  return message.reply("You don't have permission to do that.");
}

var nickname = message.content.replace("_nickname ", "");

if(nickname.trim() === ""){
  return message.reply("Enter the nickname.");
}

if(message.mentions.users.size === 0){
  return message.reply("Usage: `_nickname [mention] [nick]`");
}

message.mentions.members.forEach((member) => {
  nickname = nickname.replace("<@!" + member.id + "> ", "");
  member.setNickname(nickname).then((value) => {
    message.reply("Succeed to change nickname");
  }).catch((error) => {
    message.reply("Internal bot error");
    console.error(error);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first, it seems that your permission bit is slightly flawed, you missed `MANAGE_NICKNAMES` which is required for the bot to be able to change another member's nickname. Try using the number `1609895414`.

Now, you said:

> Also, I want to make all of these actions possible for someone with a manager role. (section 1, 2, 4)

This will be up to how you are able to develop your code, like restricting people without permissions and checking it and making sure the bot has the permission, since server admins can just remove your bot's preset permissions, this will throw an error and your bot will not respond. For this, we need to develop an error handler.

Then, You need to look at how your bot's rank in comparison to other users, you then will check if the bot has permission to do such, and if not, respond with the error hander. Error handler tend to look like this:

```js
try {
  // Some code
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

or

```js
<>.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Once that's done, you can then program your code to match the desired result.
For more info on permissions and checking them, try visiting these guides:

- [Discordjs.guide - Guide - Handling Permissions](https://discordjs.guide/commando/permissions.html#handling-permissions)
- [Discordjs.guide - Guide - Permissions](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#permissions)
- [Discord.js.org - Docs - `GuildMember` property (as used for checking and applying permissions)](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)

I assume this is how your event `message` is handled, so my suggestion will be:

```js
client.on("message", async message => { // Use `async` it's highly recommended.

  // If member doesn't have the Manage Roles permission, return, or you can use else to make a custom reply.
  // Also check if the user is an administrator, this way it doesn't need all those permissions.
  // You can require Manage Server and or other Permissions as well.
  if (!message.member.permissions.has("MANAGE_SERVER") && !clientMember.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) return;
  
  // Gets the `member` property of the `client`.
  const clientMember = message.guild.members.cache.get(client.user.id);

  // All the permissions you requested that you needed.
  // These are what's absolutely neccesary as you described.
  // The IDs of the permissions matches with their name.
  const requiredPermissions = ["MANAGE_ROLES", "MANAGE_NICKNAMES", "MANAGE_CHANNELS", "KICK_MEMBERS", "BAN_MEMBERS", "READ_MESSAGES", "SEND_MESSAGES"];
  
  // Check if the client has these permissions, check as well if the client is an administrator, this way the bot doesn't necessarily need all the permissions.
  if (!clientMember.permissions.has(requiredPermissions) && !clientMember.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) return;

  // Run your desired code after all these requirements are fulfilled.
}
```

Above is an example of how the code should be built, to answer your question about the code, try the code as follows:

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
  const kickPermissions = ["KICK_MEMBERS"]

  if(!message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR") && !message.member.permissions.has(kickPermissions)){
    return message.reply("You don't have permission to do that.");
  }

  const clientMember = message.guild.members.cache.get(client.user.id);

  if(!clientMember.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR") && !clientMember.permissions.has(kickPermissions)){
    return message.reply("The bot doesn't have permission to do that.");
  }

  if(!message.mentions.users.length){
     return message.reply("Usage: `_kick [mention]`");
  }

  message.mentions.members.forEach((member) => {
    member.kick({
      reason: "Kicked by admin"
    }).then((value) => {
      message.reply("Succeed to kick member");
    }).catch((error) => {
      message.reply("Internal bot error");
      console.error(error);
    });
  });
  
  const banPermissions = ["BAN_MEMBERS"]

  if(!message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR") && !message.member.permissions.has(banPermissions)){
    return message.reply("You don't have permission to do that.");
  }

  const clientMember = message.guild.members.cache.get(client.user.id);

  if(!clientMember.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR") && !clientMember.permissions.has(banPermissions)){
    return message.reply("The bot doesn't have permission to do that.");
  }

  if(!message.mentions.users.length){
     return message.reply("Usage: `_ban [mention]`");
  }

  message.mentions.members.forEach((member) => {
    member.ban({
      reason: "Banned by admin",
      days: 7
    }).then((value) => {
      message.reply("Succeed to ban member");
    }).catch((error) => {
      message.reply("Internal bot error");
      console.error(error);
    });
  });

  const nicknamePermissions = ["MANAGE_ROLES", "MANAGE_NICKNAMES"]

  if(!message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR") && !message.member.permissions.has(nicknamePermissions)){
    return message.reply("You don't have permission to do that.");
  }

  const clientMember = message.guild.members.cache.get(client.user.id);

  if(!clientMember.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR") && !clientMember.permissions.has(nicknamePermissions)){
    return message.reply("The bot doesn't have permission to do that.");
  }

  if(!message.mentions.users.length){
     return message.reply("Usage: `_nickname [mention]`");
  }

  var nickname = message.content.replace("_nickname ", "");

  if(nickname.trim() === ""){
    return message.reply("Enter the nickname.");
  }

  message.mentions.members.forEach((member) => {
    nickname = nickname.replace("<@!" + member.id + "> ", "");
    member.setNickname(nickname).then((value) => {
      message.reply("Succeed to change nickname");
    }).catch((error) => {
      message.reply("Internal bot error");
      console.error(error);
     });
   });
});
```

To learn more about kicking and banning members or setting their nicknames, try checking the guides below:

- [Discordjs.guide - Guide - Banning a User](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/common-questions.html#how-do-i-ban-a-user)
- [Discordjs.guide - Guide - Kicking a User](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/common-questions.html#how-do-i-kick-a-user)
- [Change user nickname with discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247353/change-user-nickname-with-discord-js)

Answer (score 1):

The `GuildMember` class has member function `hasPermission()` which return a true value if the member has that permission and false if not. You can check the discord.js documentation for addition arguments that it has from [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=hasPermission). You can check the available flags that you can pass as argument in `hasPermissions()` [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS) 
Usecase:

```js
client.on("message", msg=>{
    if(!msg.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) return;
    // It returns the function if the member doesn't have the permission and doesn't execute the code below from here.
}
```

If you want to check for specific role then you can use this

```js
member.roles.cache.has('role-id-here');
// returns true if the member has the role
```

Check discord.js guide for more indepth explanation [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#roles-as-bot-permissions)