# How do i change nickname via a command?

Tags: discord.js, bots

There's a joke on the server where when we use the command +h kidnap, and then we change the nickname to User (Kidnapper's Property), how would I go about automatically changing the nickname via the command?

```
    var rand = [
       'https://tenor.com/view/anime-kidnap-shh-reading-walking-gif-16716474',
       'https://tenor.com/view/kidnap-crazy-anime-animation-cartoon-gif-5137884',
       'https://media.tenor.com/images/5ae68746d329f3102d72d2ecc20ec1b0/tenor.gif',
       'https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/001/010/345/e2d.gif',
       'https://media1.tenor.com/images/0cb215fd5530a8e3c127095c987e455f/tenor.gif?itemid=5869143',
       'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/576014006280519701/772153347742367784/1538820468_2e00f539e9a47173911f2af39ae5ecfe96f32ae4_hq.gif',
       'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/576014006280519701/772153350057623622/1512286824_1472546756_tumblr_ockwd0wF3R1qz64n4o1_540.gif'

    ];

    return rand[Math.floor(Math.random() * rand.length)];
}

bot.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
                   case 'kidnap':
                const personTagged = message.mentions.members.first();

                if(!args[1]) {
                    message.channel.send('You are missing arguments!')
                }else{
                    message.channel.send('`' + message.author.username + '`' + ' is kidnapping ' + personTagged.displayName + '! Quick! Run! ' + doKidnapAction())
                }

            break;

   }
})
```

Again, how would I go about changing the nickname?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change user nickname with discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247353/change-user-nickname-with-discord-js)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this I belive: `personTagged.setNickname("Kidnapper's Property")`

Comment: i meant, for example is "alex" kidnapped "greg" it would show up as greg (alex's property) etc

Comment: i tried 
  ```personTagged.setNickname(" message.author.username 's property")``` , and it doesn't seem to work, am i doing this right or am i being stupid? haha

Comment: ```personTagged.setNickname(`${message.author.username}'s property`)```
of course you could also use `message.author.username+ "'s property"`
I suggest reading up on how to use variables inside strings