# it won't let me change the nickname discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

> client.on("message", async (message) => {   let roles = {
> : "Owner",
> ADMIN: "[ADM]",
> Moderador: "[MOD]",
> DcMod: "[DC]",
> Booster: "[BOOST]",
> Usuario: "[USER]"
>
> ```
> }
>
>
> let nombrerol = message.member.roles.cache.size <= 1 ? "Usuario" : message.member.roles.highest.name;
>
>
> message.member.setNickname(`${roles[nombrerol]} ${message.author.username}`) })
> ```

and I get this error

```
(node:2604) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (E:\Bots\Skyliner[RP] Bots\XD\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (E:\Bots\Skyliner[RP] Bots\XD\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
    at async GuildMember.edit (E:\Bots\Skyliner[RP] Bots\XD\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\GuildMember.js:312:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:2604) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2604) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/49866239/1935718.

Answer (score 0):

Means your bot does not have permissions to update the user's nickname. Try giving the bot those permissions and see what it does.

Comment: It only happens to me with my username
the others if it works

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the MANAGE_NICKNAMES permission assigned to the bot, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/49866239/1935718.