# why setNickname() function in discord.js is not always work?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, discord, discord.js, bots

bro.
I set the function of change the member nickname in guild for my discord robot.
The code is as follows:

```js
function setNickname(interaction, AccountName, discordId) {

         let   dotLen = (AccountName.split('.').length - 1);
         let nickname = AccountName
         if(dotLen == 2){
            nickname = nickname.replace('.aco', '');
         }
         interaction.guild.members.cache.get(discordId).setNickname(nickname);
   
 }
```

After successfully running this code, the problem arises:sometimes the nickname can be changed successfully but sometimes it cannot be changed successfully.

I ensure that the relevant permissions of the robot are sufficient.

Does anyone know the reason behind this and how to fix it, thanks a lot, bro！

In my index.js, I call the function by this line of code:

```js
await botton.setNickname(interaction,bitAccount, discordId);
```

'await' was added later by me. Before that, it was even rarer for the setnickname function to execute successfully.

So I guess it may be an asynchronous problem.

Comment: why do you `await` since `function setNickname` doesn't return anything, let alone a Promise - does `interaction.guild.members.cache.get(discordId).setNickname` return a Promsie? If so, return that

Comment: *Note that this will not work always, your client will need to have changeNickname or it won't work* - according to an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247353/change-user-nickname-with-discord-js)

Comment: thanks! After checking the documentation, I did find that it returns promise.